# Change color of TabLayout selected in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I'm new to the Android Studio and on this page, I need to know how to change the color when a tab is selected.

I've tried from the design but I'm not successful. Here is the code:

```
android:id="@+id/tab_layout_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/logo_home"
android:background="@null"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
app:tabGravity="center"
app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/content_inset_half"
app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/content_inset_half"
app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text_color_selector"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWindowsBackgroundLight"
```

Comment: What tab? `TabLayout`?

Comment: please do not truncate the class name from the XML node ...

Comment: @jake yes, I use a TabLayout, As you can see, I use a tabSelectedTextColor but I do not get the color change when I select it as indicated in the xml

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using a support library.

1...You can simply do this in your code like this:

```
 tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

2...You can, as well, do this in your xml. Add the following to your tab

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary_text"
app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary_text"
```

Your tablayout in xml will finally look like this

```
android:id="@+id/tab_layout_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/logo_home"
android:background="@null"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
app:tabGravity="center"
app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/content_inset_half"
app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/content_inset_half"
app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text_color_selector"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWindowsBackgroundLight"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary_text"
app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary_text" />
```

Comment: in which method would the code of the first option come, in OnCreate?

Comment: Under where you inflated the `TabLayout`

Comment: Like i said, i assumed you are using support library (not a custom) which should tell you that you need not a custom library, but a default `tablayout`.

Comment: If the provided answer solved the problem, you can mark it as answer to help others having same problem. If you didn't they wont be able to see the question when searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**xml code Tab layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@color/button_background"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:tabBackground="@drawable/fixed_bottom_button"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_primary_text"
app:tabMode="fixed"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary_text"
app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary_text" />
```

**Add two attributes in your tab layout like this**

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary_text"
app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary_text"
```

**Java Code**

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for the support with your answers, I used a lot of all the information I found, but the problem was that I was not using a `setText()` in the `getTabAt()` method,I was using a `setCustomView()` which was a custom view in an xml, that's why it did not change color or the `tabSelectedTextColor()` methods did not work obviously.
Just remove the custom design and use the native one manually entering the title for the tabs and with this I worked.